# Does Chrome have a built-in Call Stack?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, callstack

From Visual Studio, I'm accustomed to a call stack showing up at any breakpoint.  Does Chrome have a call stack feature where I can see what functions preceded my breakpoint?

If not, is there a substitute (3rd party solution that works with Chrome?) that developers use to see what functions led to a breakpoint?

Edit: to be clear, I was expecting the call stack to appear within the javascript console in Chrome.

Comment: Just to be sure:  You are asking about javascript debugging, correct?

Comment: Yes.  I'll modify the tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't know what version of Chrome you're using. I'm using Chromium 17 and the Javascript debugger looks like this when hitting a breakpoint (emphasis mine):
[image: Chromium call stack]

Comment: I feel like a blind fool.  Thank you!  I chose your response because you put in a picture, which I'll take to account for the minute after the first reply.  I think we could have added "RIGHT FREAKING THERE".

Answer (score 8):

Open the Developer Tools ("SPANNER" -> Tools -> Developer Tools), select the Scripts tab, on the right there is a section called "Call Stack"

Enjoy :-D

Answer (score 8):

[Version 66.0.3359.139 ]Go to Developer Tools -> Sources -> look on the right side(Call Stack).

`console.trace()`   // To print the call stack.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/print-out-a-quick-stack-trace-from-the-console

[image]