# Getting values from stdin with Node.js & TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, input, stdin, readline

I have some tasks, basically a CLI script that takes x lines, and based on said lines makes some calculations.

Eg.:

Input:

```
3 // number of iterations to do something
ATCCGCTTAGAGGGATT // first string
GTCCGTTTAGAAGGTTT // second string
// 2nd iteration starts
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
// 3rd iteration starts
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Output:

```
ATCCGCTTAGAGGGATT // first string
GTCCGTTTAGAAGGTTT // second string
*....*.....*..*.. // visual marker of differences between the two strings(*)

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
**************************

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
....................................
```

What i've tried:

```
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: ''
})

let numberOfTests = 0;
let firstText = '';
let secondText = '';
let differences = '';

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line: any) => {
  let loop = 0;
  numberOfTests = line;
  firstText = line;
  secondText = line;
  calculateDifferences(firstText, secondText); // basic function that loops through the arrays and makes the visual marker.
  loop ++;
  if (loop === numberOfTests) {
    rl.close();
  }
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log('Have a great day!');
  process.exit(0);
});
```

The main issue I am facing is that i cannot separate the input stream from one another.
By the time we are at the secondText every variable will be equal to wheter I input on the 3rd time.

How can you separate the inputs from each other?

[Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) is not so detailed about this.Or I cannot see it through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution to differenciate the rl instances.

[Following this comment is 100% working in my use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790818/8939031)