# Readline works only for the first time

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node's `readline` but it works only for the first time. 
At the first try everything works well (`answer` is logged and `readline` is closed) but another time it looks like the `readline` is not being closed (`answer` is never logged and console is still waiting for my input even if I've already sent it).

I've class in Node.js (using ES6 with Babel and Nodemon) which has `readline` in constructor.

```js
class SomeClass
{
    constructor(readline) {
        this.readline = readline;
    }

    askPath() {
        this.readline.question('Question: ', (answer) => {
            console.log(answer);
            this.readline.close();
            this.askPath();
        });
    }
}

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let someClass = new SomeClass(rl);
someClass.askPath();
```

Console looks like:

```
> Question: answer
> answer
> Question: second answer
> I can still write
> nothing happens...
```

Comment: just don't close readline interface in your callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take two consecutive input with the readline module of node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540996/how-to-take-two-consecutive-input-with-the-readline-module-of-node-js)

Comment: `close()` closes whole instance? I thought it just close input listener. I think the question which has you mentioned is a different kind of question. I've only one instance of readline with misused close function. You can provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't call the `.close()` function, inside of your callback as it closes the entire readline interface

```
askPath() {
    this.readline.question('Question: ', (answer) => {
        console.log(answer);
        this.askPath();
    });
}
```

---

As the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_close) says:

> The rl.close() method **closes the readline.Interface instance** and relinquishes control over the input and output streams. [source:nodejs.org]