# Loop that calls a readline prompt (and then itself) only calls once and then exits the program (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, loops

I have some code that I am trying to use to train a neural network, in this case, the NPM module `natural`. Instead of manually typing in the training code, I thought I could do it all through the command line as I have used `readline` before and it was relatively easy.

Because the function loops over an array of values, before this I used a `for` loop, but it wouldn't wait for you to type, I had to set a specific timeout that I multiplied by the number of iterations. This worked, but I didn't like it because I went away from the computer for a couple of minutes and it basically deleted all of my progress (in training the network) because it threw an error:

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [ReadStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Obviously I could extend the max listeners, but it is much more elegant to wait for the user to finish typing.

Back to my main question, why doesn't the below code work?

```js
let natural = require('natural');
let fs = require('fs')
const readline = require("readline");


let file = fs.readFileSync('./expansions.txt')
let splitted = file.toString().split('\n')

let classifier = new natural.BayesClassifier();

getInfo(0)
function getInfo(i){
    if(i < splitted.length){
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });
        rl.question("Do you like this acronym? " + splitted[i] + ' (y or n) > ', function(bool) {
            // receives the correct input
            console.log(bool)
            if(bool.toString() === 'y'){
                getInfo(i + 1)
                classifier.addDocument(splitted[i], 'y')
            } else if(bool.toString() === 'n'){
                classifier.addDocument(splitted[i], 'n')
                getInfo(i + 1)
            } else {
                // seems to always loop back to this
                getInfo(i)
            }
            rl.close();
        });
    }
}

classifier.train();
```

At first I thought that it wasn't reading my input correctly, so I logged the value of `bool` and got the correct value. I also ran `.toString()` on it while checking, but I don't think it has anything to do with that, because the exact same code worked in a `for` loop.

Here is the output:

```
Do you like this? I am trying to be funny. (y or n) > y
Do you like this? I am trying to be funny. (y or n) >
C:\Users\divinelemon\Downloads\Programming\Node.js\neural-network-generator>
```

Notice that it's supposed to go on to the next item in the array, `serving static files like turtles strapped to rockets`, but it stays on the first one and exits the program.

What is going on here?

Comment: You're expecting the user to enter y or n, but you're checking for t and n.

Shouldn't the first if statement be: if(bool.toString() === 'y')

Also, in the callback you're already getting a string, so I don't think the toString is even necessary: if(bool === 'y')

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi sorry, I just noticed that. However, it does the exact same thing editing that error like you noticed. Thanks for trying! (I will edit the code snippet to clarify)

Comment: You are calling close at the wrong time. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540996/how-to-take-two-consecutive-input-with-the-readline-module-of-node-js

You should basically have one instance of rl that is reused.

Also, as an FYI, your classifier.train(); at the end will be called before you answer the questions. Not sure if you're aware of that. Readline is not synchronous (most things are not in Node).